# Should election score be locked at the values of the election?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, election, nominations

I think that the election score of the candidates should be fixed, i.e. show the score, the badges and the reputation as they were when the election ended. I think this appropriate when one wants to look why one wasn't elected in an earlier election.